# How to map single JSON field to multiple JAVA field with GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to parse JSON using Retrofit and Gson, but I need to map one JSONfield
's value to multiple JAVA fields inside bean class.

Here is an example code:

```
class A{

@SerializedName("name");
private String name;

@SerializedName("name");
private String fullName;

}
```

This is the error I'm seeing: class A declares multiple JSON fields named name. Is there any way to do this?

Update: Please avoid suggesting removing one field from the bean or making changes into getter and setter. The project is huge, and the field is being used later in many other cases, so I don't want to mess with the structure. The question is pretty much clear and on the point.

Comment: can you provide your json response example

Comment: You can achieve this with custom gson deserializers: http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

But your question sounds weird. As I guess there is other way to do what you need instead of mapping one json filed to multiple java fields.

Maybe something like this:
`
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return name
}
`

Comment: Or if you want separate setters, then you can have something like:
`
public String getFullName() {
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(fullName) ? name : fullName;
}
`

Comment: It doesn't make sens ... just remove fullName at all if you wana store the same value there

Comment: @VishalSanghani You can assume the JSON like this:  { "name" : "foo" }

Answer (score -2):

No need to declare JSON for fullname use name value with fullname in setter gatter.

```
class A{

        @SerializedName("name");
        private String name;

        private String fullName;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getFullName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setFullName(String fullName) {
            this.name = fullName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And some day some pitty programmer will try to guess why on hell name had change when he just setted the fullName ... setFullName should set only fullName ...

Comment: @Selvin I just showed him how he can achieve both variables with the same insertion. You shouldn't judge it. And why you gave a downvote to this answer? Is there any loophole, error or programmatic fault.

Comment: *You shouldn't judge it.* Why? ... setter should be setter ... what if on coffee machine would be the button with "coffee with milk" but when you press it the machin would server hot engine oil? ... **also this not an answers to the question** which is: *How to map single JSON field to multiple JAVA field with GSON?*

Comment: Yes the thing I already mention before code "No need to declare JSON for fullname use name value with fullname in setter gatter."

Comment: @ReadyAndroid I can't. If I have declared two fields, there is obviously some reason. The field is used in many other cases and modified later. I just want its value to be same as other field initially.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid Make that two downvotes dude. He said two fields, NOT two methods. Like Selvin said, I don't want my setter and getter pointing to the same variable... (especially since in my case, the fields are different types).

Comment: @KrustytheClown if fields are different types then no one is going to help you rather than of backend developer. Just ask BE team to pass another field for another type...

Comment: Also, I didn't mention two methods, my use case was simple as per his(@ZainUlAbdin) requirements. He wants single JSON field mapping with 2 params which is not possible in auto JSON parsing so I showed him how to set and get that same value in a different variable. This is as simple as if the API response has a first name and last name in two different params and needs to show the full name in the UI and then create a different function in model class only rather than concat at every usage.
For other developers, just add one note to the variable so they know the use case before any change.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid **I AM THE BACKEND DEVELOPER DUDE!** We're pulling data from a somewhat poorly formatted JSON API where `someJSONFieldName` can represent two fields, where one is an int and one a String; if it's one, we null the other. And I can't use something like your solution and just `Integer.parseInt` every time (despite how inefficient that is...) because we base our columns off of variables. For your own good, stop trying to defend your solution and just admit it's lackluster.

Comment: @KrustytheClown thanks for your advice. Did you get the solution yet? If yes, then please share so I can also overcome this "lackluster"...

Comment: @ReadyAndroid I just used a GSON deserializer, someone already mentioned it in the comment below OP.

Comment: "You can achieve this with custom gson deserializers: javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example But your question sounds weird." answered by  
krossovochki. I am not able to find the exact example link that might be changed to some different path https://codebeach.com/java-homework-help/. Could you please share the exact example that has been used by you?